# appending rows to a list as part of a loop Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am getting data from an Oracle database. Some of the data is in clob format (column 8), so I must loop through each row and convert. I want to append each row that gets converted to form the original table again. The line giving me trouble is `Complete_data = [Complete_data, fixed_data]`

```
import cx_Oracle
# USE THIS CONNECTION STRING FOR PRODUCTION
production_username = ''
production_password = ''

con_string = '%s/%s@host' % (production_username, production_password)
con = cx_Oracle.connect(con_string)
cursor = con.cursor()
querystring = ("Select * from SalesDatabase")
cursor.execute(querystring)
data = cursor.fetchall()

#loop through and convert clobs to readable content
for currentrow in data:
    Product = currentrow[8].read()
    fixed_data = ([currentrow[0], currentrow[1], currentrow[2], currentrow[3], currentrow[4], currentrow[5], currentrow[6], currentrow[7], Product, currentrow[9]])
    Complete_data = [Complete_data, fixed_data]

 con.close()
 print Complete_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way to populate a list, is to create an empty list to start with, and `append` items to it within a loop.

```
Complete_data = []
for currentrow in data:
    Product = currentrow[8].read()
    fixed_data = ([currentrow[0], currentrow[1], currentrow[2], currentrow[3], currentrow[4], currentrow[5], currentrow[6], currentrow[7], Product, currentrow[9]])
    Complete_data.append(fixed_data)
```